# ASP.NetCore OData DTO $expand navigation property results in empty array

Tags: odata, automapper, dto, expand, ef-core-2.2

I am using Entity Framework with OData to get data from my mysql database but I don't want to expose database entites to the user, so I've created some DTO's and map them with Automapper.
My Problem is that everything works fine except loading entities with $expand.

There are 2 Entities with 2 DTO's (in my project the dto's and domain models do not look the same, this is only for better reading):

```
public partial class Product
{       

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }        

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }     
    public virtual ICollection<ProductPrice> ProductPrices { get; set; }   
}

public class ProductDTO
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductPriceDTO> ProductPrices { get; set; }
    public virtual CategoryDTO Category { get; set; }
}

public partial class Category
{     
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }         
}

public class CategoryDTO
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public partial class ProductPrice
{
    public string VendorId { get; set; }
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
}

public class ProductPriceDTO
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Vendor")]
    public string VendorId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Product")]
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public virtual VendorDTO Vendor { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductDTO Product { get; set; }
}
```

The models are created the following way:

```
 public IEdmModel GetEdmModel(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(serviceProvider);
        builder.Namespace = "Functions";            
        //category
        builder.EntitySet<CategoryDTO>("Categories").EntityType.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Count().Page();
        //product
        builder.EntitySet<ProductDTO>("Products").EntityType.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Count().Page();           
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
        //productprice
        builder.EntitySet<ProductPriceDTO>("ProductPrices").EntityType.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Count().Page();
    }
```

Automapper profile:

```
public AutoMapperProfile()
    {            
        CreateMap<Product, ProductDTO>()
            .ForMember(dto => dto.Category, conf => conf.AllowNull())
            .ForMember(dto => dto.ProductPrices, dest => dest.MapFrom(x => x.ProductPrices))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.ProductPrices, dest => dest.ExplicitExpansion())
            .ForMember(dto => dto.ProductPrices, conf => conf.AllowNull());
        CreateMap<ProductPrice, ProductPriceDTO>()
            .ForMember(dto => dto.Product, conf => conf.AllowNull())
            .ForMember(dto => dto.Vendor, conf => conf.AllowNull());            
    }
```

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
[ODataRoutePrefix("Products")]
public class ProductsController : BaseODataController
{
    private readonly IProductService ProductService;
    private readonly IProductPriceService ProductPriceService;

    public ProductsController(IMapper mapper, IProductService productService, IProductPriceService productPriceService) : base(mapper)
    {
        ProductService = productService;
        ProductPriceService = productPriceService;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<ProductDTO> Get(ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        var query = ProductService.QueryProducts();
        string[] includes = GetExpandNamesFromODataQuery(queryOptions);
        if (includes != null && includes.Length > 0)
        {
            return query.ProjectTo<ProductDTO>(null, includes);
        }
        return query.ProjectTo<ProductDTO>();           
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [EnableQuery]
    [ODataRoute("({key})")]
    public IQueryable<ProductDTO> Get([FromODataUri] string key, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        var query = ProductService.QueryProducts().Where(x => x.Id.Equals(key));
        string[] includes = GetExpandNamesFromODataQuery(queryOptions);
        if (includes != null && includes.Length > 0)
        {
            return query.ProjectTo<ProductDTO>(null, includes);
        }
        return query.ProjectTo<ProductDTO>();
    }        
}
```

As I mentioned above every query works fine ($select, $filter, $orderBy, $count).
But when I call the following:

> https://localhost:44376/odata/Products('631794')?$expand=Category

I get:

> {"@odata.context":"https://localhost:44376/odata/$metadata#Products","value":[

as response.

In the output of Visual Studio there is a message:

> No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.Int16' and 'System.Boolean'.

I think there must be something wrong with the Automapper profile. As I read somewhere .ProjectTo() with include parameters creates a Select to get the related data from the navigation property. I thought it is enough to create the relation with [ForeignKey] in the DTO.

Comment: Can you post the AutoMapper configuration of the sample model?

Comment: I have added the Automapper configuration.

Comment: I can't reproduce (not sure what AM version are you using), but seems like AM by default is generating null check expression which is causing client evaluation (and might have other side effects). Try adding `.ForMember(dto => dto.Category, conf => conf.AllowNull())` to the second map and see if that helps.

Comment: This solved my problem! Thank you!